# How to link a python if else with a html/javascript checkbox function

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, aws-lambda

how could i make my Javascript checkboxes work with my python invocation code?

Explanation: I have a html page with some check boxes that javascript interacts with. I now need to make it so that whenever a check box is selected my python code knows to run through an if else and invoke that specific option and if nothing is selected to break. I am fairly new in JS and python but thanks in advance.

This is the python code:

```
    publicaccess = client.invoke(
    FunctionName = en['Public_Accessibility'],
    InvocationType = 'RequestResponse',
    Payload = json.dumps(event)
)

bucket_acl = client.invoke(
    FunctionName = en['Bucket_Acl'],
    InvocationType = 'RequestResponse',
    Payload = json.dumps(event)
)
```

and these are my checkbox options:
[Image of my checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DMzy.png)

This is my html and JS.

```js
// function valthis() {
// var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByName( "scans" );
// var isChecked = false;
//     for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
//         if ( checkBoxes[i].checked ) {
//             isChecked = true;
//         };
//     };
//     if ( isChecked ) {
//         alert( "At least one checkbox checked, proceed!" );
//         } else {
//             alert( "Please, check at least one checkbox!" );
//         }
// }
const frm1 = document.getElementById("form");
console.log("Api key value is: " + frm1)

function check_all() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("scans");
  checkboxes = [...checkboxes];
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = true
  }
}

function un_check_all() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("scans");
  checkboxes = [...checkboxes];
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = false;
  }
}
// const button = document.querySelector("#button");
// button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
//     alert(getSelectedCheckboxValues("scans"));
// });
function Submit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let x = document.forms["myForm"]["apikey"].value;
  console.log(x)
  if (x == "") {
    alert("Must Insert Api Key and Select a Scan Option");
    return false;
  }
  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append("x-api-key", x);
  console.log(myHeaders);

  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: myHeaders
    // 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'application/json',
    // 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    // 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST,GET',
  }; {
    var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByName("scans");
    var isChecked = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
      if (checkBoxes[i].checked) {
        isChecked = true;
      };
    };
    if (!isChecked) {
      alert("Please, check at least one checkbox!");
      return false;
    }
  }
  // const button = document.querySelector("#button");
  // button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  //     alert(getSelectedCheckboxValues("scans"));
  // });


  fetch("https://jw1yko5ctd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Project", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .then(() => {
      alert("Scan ran, await email notification.")
    })
    .then(successpage => {
      window.location.href = "http://localhost:8000/Successpage.html"
      // window.open("file:///Users/okunawod/Desktop/ProjectProgression/Testing/Successpage.html")
      // console.log(window)
    })
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  // alert("pretendtosend")
  return false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Security Scanner</title>
</head>

<h1>Security Scanner</h1>

<body>
  <div>Choose Scan Options: (please select at least one)</div>
  <p></p>
  <div>
    <input type="button" name="Check_All" value="Select All" onClick="check_all()">
    <input type="button" id="clearAll" value="Clear All" onClick="un_check_all();">
    <p></p>
    <div>
      <label for="public access"> <input type="checkbox" name="scans" value="public access" id="scantype1" required />Public Accessiblity</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="bucket acl"><input type="checkbox" name="scans" value="bucket acl" id="scantype2" />Bucket Acl</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="placeholder1"><input type="checkbox" name="scans" value="placeholder1" id="scantype3" />Placeholder1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="placeholder2"><input type="checkbox" name="scans" value="placeholder2" id="scantype4" />Placeholder2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="placeholder3"><input type="checkbox" name="scans" value="placeholder3" id="scantype5" />Placeholder3</label>
    </div>
    <!--   <button id="button" type="submit" onclick="valthis()">Confirm Scan Options</button> -->
    <br>
    <br>
    <form id="frm1" name="myForm" type="text" onsubmit="Submit(event)" method="post">
      Api Key: <input type="text" name="apikey">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <script src="Project.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, you should share your JavaScript as that is the only way to see what you've tried so far. Are you running a server instance for your Python code in order for the web page and Python code to communicate with each other? If so, how are you making your requests on the front end? Your JS code and support HTML would better answer these questions

Comment: @SteveHynding Yes I'm running a server on my local machine to allow for my webpage to call my api from aws lambda specifically